# org.freedesktop.accounts.change-own-user-data asks me for password

Tags: password, authentication

I'm on Ubuntu 15.10. with multiple users configured.

Each time I switch to another user and come back to my account, I have a prompt windows asking me to enter my password. Sometimes it works, sometimes the windows stay on top.

Details section says it's related to `org.freedesktop.accounts.change-own-user-data`. It is often associated with a freeze of status bar and Dock Bar.

It's really annoying. How can I fix this?

EDIT:
as requested:

```
find "$HOME" ! \( -user "$USER" -readable -writable \) -ls 2>/dev/null
41418905    4 drwx------   4 root     root         4096 nov. 18 18:48 /home/jerome/Bureau/GAYOUNETTE/.mozilla/firefox
49021221    4 drwx------   2 root     root         4096 nov. 18 18:48 /home/jerome/Bureau/GAYOUNETTE/.mozilla/extensions
49154054    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 jerome   jerome         16 janv. 12 22:45 /home/jerome/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock -> jerome-NUC-11436
49155854    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 jerome   jerome         17 janv. 12 22:45 /home/jerome/.config/google-chrome/SingletonCookie -> 60601084509665078
41160168    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 jerome   jerome         14 oct.  1 02:32 /home/jerome/Documents/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock -> PC-Jerome-2035
41160171    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 jerome   jerome         46 oct.  1 02:32 /home/jerome/Documents/.config/google-chrome/SingletonSocket -> /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.fo9tHf/SingletonSocket
41160172    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 jerome   jerome         19 oct.  1 02:32 /home/jerome/Documents/.config/google-chrome/SingletonCookie -> 4561439250107276978
49156066    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 jerome   jerome          8 janv.  2 23:04 /home/jerome/.wine/dosdevices/f:: -> /dev/sdd
49156060    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 jerome   jerome          8 janv.  2 23:04 /home/jerome/.wine/dosdevices/e:: -> /dev/sdc
49156112    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 jerome   jerome          9 janv.  2 23:04 /home/jerome/.wine/dosdevices/g:: -> /dev/sdc1
49156617    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 jerome   jerome          1 nov. 25 19:03 /home/jerome/.wine/dosdevices/z: -> /
49154485    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 jerome   jerome          9 janv.  2 23:04 /home/jerome/.wine/dosdevices/d:: -> /dev/sdd2
```

Comment: Considering [this question](/questions/562355/seemingly-random-authentication-is-required-to-change-your-own-user-data), what's the output of `find "$HOME" ! \( -user "$USER" -readable -writable \) -ls 2>/dev/null`?

Comment: output edited in first post...

Comment: Thanks. Apart from all those (broken) symlinks I see some files in `/home/jerome/Bureau/GAYOUNETTE/.mozilla` are owned by `root` instead of your user account. This seems to be unintentional and may cause issues, though probably not the one at hand.